# Spark Scala: Issue Substituting Filter Expression In DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe created which holds the join of 2 tables.

I want to compare each field of table1 to that of table2 (Schema is same)
 Columns in Table A = colA1, colB1, colC1 , ...
 Columns in Table B = colA2, colB2, colC2, ...
 So, I need to filter out the data which satisfies the condition

(colA1 = colA2) AND (colB1 = colB2) AND (colC1 = colC2) and so on.
 Since my table has a lot of fields, I tried to build a similar exp.

```
 val filterCols = Seq("colA","colB","colC")
 val sq = '"'
 val exp = filterCols.map({ x => s"(join_df1($sq${x}1$sq) === join_df1($sq${x}2$sq))" }).mkString(" && ")
 Resultant Exp : res28: String = (join_df1("colA1") === join_df1("colA2")) && (join_df1("colB1") === join_df1("colB2")) && (join_df1("colC1") === join_df1("colC2"))
```

Now when i try to substitute it to the dataframe, it throws me an error.
 join_df1.filter($exp)

I am not sure whether I am doing it right .I need to find a way to substitute my expression and filter out value.
 Any help is appreciated.

[image]Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid SQL. Try:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  ("a", "A", "b", "B", "c", "C")).toDF("a1", "a2", "b1", "b2", "c1", "c2")

val filterCols = Seq("A", "B", "C")

val exp = filterCols.map(x => s"${x}1 = ${x}2").mkString(" AND ")
df.where(exp)
```

Comment: Hi @LostInOverflow: Building the expression worked for me(I have the resultant expression also pasted in my question). But when I tried to place this in the dataframe filter, it throws me error.

Comment: I tried it adding the enclosing brackets as well. Now the syntax worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now the issue is that I am not getting any values in the final filter. I tried all combinations which gets satisfied to get the result.

Comment: I edited question to provide minimal proof that it works.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution helped :)